# Is it quicker to access a local variable than an attribute of an object?

Tags: performance

Straight-forward language agnostic question. I've always done this:

```
myVar = myObj.myAttribute
```

when I need to access myAttribute a lot.

I'm wondering if this is just a superstition I've acquired, or if it's generally faster?

Edit: I would also like to know if this

```
myVar = myObj.myAttribute/100
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    print myVar*i;
}
```

is more efficient than putting (myObj.myAttribute/100) in the loop. Will modern compilers and interpreters detect that that part of the equation doesn't vary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case what you did is more efficient, since it's one division vs 100.

I do property assign to variables only if I can optimize the operations done later, like in your case or expect multiple calls to the same property and the object lookup is likely to be expensive. Generally using local variable should be the more cpu wize way, since it can be costly to do complex property lookups, along with the better control of that property value and possible pre-validation before looping. That said it may be inefficient only if the lookup is likely to occur once or twice for the function call, thus adding overhead and making the code harder to follow up.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it might depend on the language, and/or the compiler ; but, generally speaking, the less your code has to do, the faster it'll be.

But the difference shouldn't be that important... and what matters the most is people are able to understand your code easily.

In Javascript, for instance, it's said that it's faster using a local variable instead of re-calculating object-access several times.

i.e. this :

```
var a = obj.a.b.c;
a.a = 10;
a.b = 20;
a.c = 30:
```

is faster than that :

```
obj.a.b.c.a = 10;
obj.a.b.c.b = 20;
obj.a.b.c.c = 30:
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, depending on the language, maybe.

You are unlikely to notice the difference however, unless you are running (for example) a tight loop.

Usually I would say the savings are not worth the extra cognitive load on the programmer.

However if you have a bit of code which you know has a slowness problem, this kind of optimisation is definitely worth considering.